# Nextcloud 16: automatic import contacts (.csv)

Tags: linux, contacts, nextcloud

currently i´ve installed a fresh nextcloud 16 service on an ubuntu 18 LTS server. 
Nextcloud working fine, i´ve added the "Contacts" App on the Web GUI.

When i add an contact at the Gui, it is possible to sync it via carddav with my iPhone.

We need to import some Contact Lists (.csv) to the contact service on nextcloud. Is it possible to create an automatic import from any local path on the linux srv? 
Example: every day at 23:00 we should import an .csv contactlist from /media/contacts/ (via cronjob!?) to the specific nextcloud account contact app!

thank you for your ideas!

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be** more appropriate for https://superuser.com or https://apple.stackexchange.com , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.